# scheduled script much more slow than running manually

Tags: script, task-scheduler

I have a backup script that uses robocopy to copy files from my computer to an external USB drive.

I added the script to Windows 7 Task Scheduler. It works, but it takes around 4 hours to copy everything.

If I run the script manually it takes around 45 to 50 minutes.

I enabled the "Run with highest privileges" option.

Any ideas why it's so slow when running from the task scheduler?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - http://learningpcs.blogspot.in/2012/06/powershell-v2-set-process-priority-on.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks!, this was a step in the correct direction. What I did was export the task to XML. modify the Priority to 4 (normal) and then import the new task. More info here:http://bdbits.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/setting-a-scheduled-task-process-priority/

Comment: Yes! Export to XML, delete the task, open the XML with notepad, change priority to 4, and Import the task. Worked wonders for me.